# Uploading documents to another users MySite

Tags: list, document-library, my-site

In our scenario we have students and each students has his own MySite and we also have teachers of those students. My question is: is there any out-of-the-box way/feature where teachers could upload documents/add items to lists in students MySites?

### EDIT:

I actually managed to enable users to upload documents to Shared Documents library (adding contribute for specified users). The thing is, that after uploading document to library it is visible for user who uploaded and for mysite owner (in list view). But this document is not visible in Content tab in user profile. It becomes visible after site owner modifies it (modified by column changes to site owner, not original uploader) - any ideas how I could overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I used this silverlight component:

[Codeplex: Silverlight File Upload](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/)